# Android remote debugging suddenly stops working

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

I followed the instructions for Chrome remote debugging here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

It worked just fine. However, a few days later day, when I plugged in my phone, it says "device not detected". I didn't do anything to the phone or the laptop. All I did was turn it off and on again. I did go on a trip to another town, but I didn't think I did anything that would affect either phone or laptop.

I tried different cables, and I'm still getting the same "device not detected" message. I revoked the debugging permission and replugged it in, and I'm not even getting the RSA fingerprint prompt. I tried doing this on a different laptop, and I'm still not getting the RSA prompt.

What exactly went wrong here?

Comment: I do not know about how Remote debugging works. But I am using Stetho Facebook library for debugging application on Chrome using Chrome://inspect.

Comment: What device do you need? http://www.ironlab.io allows debugging on real devices in the cloud. They are in free beta now.